# Constructor error: How can set these properties through parameterize constructor?

Tags: java, oop, error-handling, compiler-errors, syntax-error

**1. how can set these properties through parametrize constructor??**

**Class file**

```
public class Product{
    private String Name;
    private String Color;
    private int Price;
    private int Stock;
    private int SKU;
```

1. **I want to set these properties thorough the setter passing by parametrize constructor but it did not set these properties**

   ```
   public void setName(String Name){
       this.Name=Name;
   }
   public void setColor(String Color){
       this.Color=Color;
   }
   public void setPrice(int Price){
       if (Price <= 0){
           System.out.println("Price can't be 0 or negative");
       }
       else{this.Price=Price;
       }

   }
   public void setStock(int Stock){
       if(Stock == 0){
           System.out.println("Stock not avaible");
       }
       else{
           this.Stock=Stock;
       }

   }
   public void setSKU(int SKU){
       if(SKU<6){
           System.out.println("Manimum allow quntity is 6");
       }
       else{
           this.SKU=SKU;
       }
   }
   ```
2. **Here I want to show me properties through toString method**

   ```
   public String toString(){
       return "\nProduct name: " + this.Name + "\nProduct color: " + this.Color + "\nProduct price: " + this.Price + "\nProduct stock: " + this.Stock + "\nProduct SKU: " + this.SKU;
   }

   Product(){}

   //parametriaz constractor
   Product(String Name,String Color,int Price,int Stock,int SKU){
       System.out.println("Run");
       setName(Name);
       setColor(Color);
       setPrice(Price);
       setStock(Stock);
       setSKU(SKU);
       toString();
   }
   ```

   }
   **Object file**
3. **Why I am unable to set these properties through constructor??**

   public class Runnable{
   public static void main(String [] args){
   Product p1 = new Product("pc","Grey",5000,10,2);

   ```
           //This line also give error why??
           //p1.Product("pc","Grey",5000,10,2);
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: can you add the error also that you are getting?

Comment: Please show complete, runnable code. If you have an error, you need to say exactly what the error is.

Comment: What do you think the statement `p1.Product("pc","Grey",5000,10,2);` will do?

Comment: Runnable.java:4: error: cannot find symbol
                p1.Product("pc","Grey",5000,10,2);
                  ^
  symbol:   method Product(String,String,int,int,int)
  location: variable p1 of type Product

Comment: @tgdavies i want to pass these values to parametrized constructor then through parametrized constructor pass to setter and then get these values through toString() method which is calling in Constructor

Comment: public class Runnable{ public static void main(String [] args){ Product p1 = new Product("pc","Grey",5000,10,2);

        //This line also give error why??
        //p1.Product("pc","Grey",5000,10,2);
    }
}

Comment: What do you expect the line `p1.Product("pc","Grey",5000,10,2)` to do?

Comment: And what makes you think that your fields are not getting set?

Comment: The `toString()` method returns a String. It doesn't perform any IO.

Comment: p1.Product("pc","Grey",5000,10,2) through this pass values to constructor

Comment: ok 
thnaks i got a point

Comment: you mean p1.Product("pc","Grey",5000,10,2) this line  aren't  need to call the parametrized constructor

Answer (score 0):

By Convention, Field names are cameCased and lowerCase.

```java
public class Product {
    private String name;
    private String color;
    private int price;
    private int stock;
    private int sku;

    Product() {
    }

    //Parameterized constructor
    Product(String name, String color, int price, int stock, int sku) {
        System.out.println("Run");
        this.setName(name);
        this.setColor(color);
        this.setPrice(price);
        this.setStock(stock);
        this.setSku(sku);
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getColor() {
        return color;
    }

    public void setColor(String color) {
        this.color = color;
    }

    public int getPrice() {
        return price;
    }

    public void setPrice(int price) {
        if (price <= 0) {
            System.out.println("Price can't be 0 or negative");
        } else {
            this.price = price;
        }

    }

    public int getStock() {
        return stock;
    }

    public void setStock(int stock) {
        if(stock == 0){
            System.out.println("Stock not avaible");
        }
        else{
            this.stock=stock;
        }
    
    }

    public int getSku() {
        return sku;
    }

    public void setSku(int sku){
        if(sku<6){
            System.out.println("Manimum allow quntity is 6");
        }
        else{
            this.sku=sku;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Product [color=" + color + ", name=" + name + ", price=" + price + ", sku=" + sku + ", stock=" + stock
                + "]";
    }



    //Consume
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.println("using Constructor only");
        Product p = new Product("pc","Grey",5000,10,2);   // Right way to call contructor
        System.out.println(p); // Prints the object using toString()
        
        //OR
        System.out.println(new Product("pc","Grey",5000,10,2));

        //OR
        System.out.println("using Setters and getters only");
        Product p1 = new Product();
        p1.setName("pc");
        p1.setColor("Grey");
        p1.setPrice(5000);
        p1.setStock(10);
        p1.setSku(2);

        System.out.println(p1);
    }

}
```

```sh
❯ java Product.java
using Constructor only
Run
Manimum allow quntity is 6
Product [color=Grey, name=pc, price=5000, sku=0, stock=10]
Run
Manimum allow quntity is 6
Product [color=Grey, name=pc, price=5000, sku=0, stock=10]
using Setters and getters only
Manimum allow quntity is 6
Product [color=Grey, name=pc, price=5000, sku=0, stock=10]
```